# Is it possible to pass parameters to collection members in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I have a collection called opcodes and created a loop to generate a listing of all the members. In abbreviated form:

```
{% assign ops = site.opcodes | where: 'pst', 1 %}
{% for opcode in ops %}
<div id="op{{ opcode.n }}" class="opcode">
  <span class="op-data">#{{ opcode.n }} ({{ opcode.n | dec_to_hex }})</span>
  {{ opcode.content }}
{% endfor %}
```

The individual members are html files with some front matter. I'll be generating several listings and the members sometimes need to change slightly. It looks like by the time the loop runs, their content is already generated though. I tried affecting their front matter or site variables, but this is all too late, none of the liquid if statements work. The variables are either empty or at their original values.

**Is there a way to make this work, somehow pass parameters to the members before their content gets rendered?**

The obvious fix is to just copy the problematic files and edit them, since I'm already using a "where" clause to select them. The question is about any better ways.

EDIT: this is how the individual files look like:

```
---
title: bla
pst = 0
---
bla bla
{% if x == "big" %}
  blu blu
{% else %}
  ble ble
{% endif %}
```

`x` is what I'd like to set externally, from the first loop.

Comment: Not really easy to understand your question. Can you add some input datas, variable names, desired output in your sentences ? It can help understand what goes wrong.

Comment: I've added a simplified version of the collection members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've looked at it again, but found no solution, so the answer appears to be: no, it is not possible to pass parameters to collection members before they get rendered.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [front matter default configuration](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/#front-matter-defaults) to set variable depending on containing folder.

```
─ _myCol
   ├── cat1
   │   ├── item0.md
   │   └── item1.md
   └── cat2
       ├── item2.md
       └── item3.md
```

If you want to set a variable `myVar` for all you items in `myCol` collection, you do :

```
# _config.yml
defaults:
  - scope:
      type: myCol
    values:
      myVar: "YOLO"
```

Now if you want to set a different value for `myVar` depending on containing folder, you add :

```
- scope:
    path: _myCol/cat1
  values:
    myVar: "TOTO"
```

You can then use this variable in your collection's item layout, like this :

```
{% if page.myVar == "YOLO" %}
  blu blu
{% else %}
  ble ble
{% endif %}
```

Comment: But this is the same as just defining different front matter variables — there's no need for extra folders and duplicated items. Furthermore, changing frontmatter variables from outside the loop had no effect, presumably since the content was already rendered.

Comment: Default config + folders allows a little automation. But you're free to use front matter editing. But I still don't understand what is your problem with content. Which part of content is supposed to be "dynamic" and how ?

Comment: In your case "page.myVar", which I would set before the loop of my first snippet. There'll be about 6 pages with the same _layout_ and some would have to set that or any other var to slightly change the item.

Comment: "slightly change the item" inside `page.content` ?

Comment: Yes, like the presented if-statement.